# Invoking an audio-based Google Assistant action via Bluetooth headset

Tags: android, google-assistant, app-actions

I'm attempting to develop an Android application whose primary means of interaction is via audio, and whose primary mode of invocation will be via a Google Assistant App Action shortcut, typically via a Bluetooth headset.

Beyond the inherent challenges of developing such an app (e.g., it's not possible to test out the interaction using a Bluetooth headset until the application is actually published to the Play Store), I'm seeing some anomalies in the way other applications behave when invoked in this manner :

1. Most applications generate an error (played back via Bluetooth audio) that says "Sorry… that shortcut will only work on an Android phone with that app installed", but the app still launches on the phone.  This is not entirely unexpected.
2. Other applications that play audio (e.g., Spotify) follow the shortcut and launch the app, but don't play an error message.  Also, not unexpected, however...
3. Some non-audio apps (e.g., Facebook, Cash App, LinkedIn, and Instagram), launch on the phone and do *not* play the error message.

So my question is what is it in the app (I'm guessing something in the manifest, though it might also be some return status) that results in the error message not being played? I couldn't find any documentation regarding this or even anyone else who has run into this error message.